# Sikuli Key.CTRL does not work

Tags: sikuli

Using Sikuli IDE 1.0.1 (according to the "About SikuliX" menu).

Ubuntu 14.04.3, 64 bit, virtual server, via tightvnc + Xfce 4.

One day everything just stopped working though we did not change the sources. Server updates (ubuntu software) are off. Combinations like type('a', Key.CTRL) started to type plain 'a' char, not selecting a text (as before).

We even tried to spin up the same instance type, set everything up there, and run agian. And Sikuli failed to type "Ctrl" again!

We also tried to run the script with "-r", skipping IDE. Same thing - no Ctrl.

Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should do it as sequential actions (like you actually do on your keyboard):

```
keyDown(Key.CTRL)
type("a")
keyUp(Key.CTRL)
```

Alternatively, you can use the `KeyModifier.CTRL` in the function `type`

```
type("a", KeyModifier.CTRL)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the

```
type('a', Key.CTRL)
```

to simulate holding CTRL and pressing the 'a' key, the method you're using has been depricated. It should more properly be

```
type('a', KeyModifier.CTRL)
```

as per the [documentation](http://doc.sikuli.org/keys.html?highlight=keymodifier#KeyModifier).

Try that and see if that will solve your problem. :)

Comment: I'm sure this is too late to help you, Spaceman, but for future readers, having NumLock on often makes my "Key.CTRL" combinations stop working. It's a [known bug](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/143874)...